# Pandas pivot any columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-melt

Does anyone have any idea how to do this in Pandas?

I have this data frame:

```
Uf  IBGE    CNES    2020    2021
ES  320120  2547678 2747    2916
ES  320120  2485656 1817    2071
ES  320120  3125416 2965    3156
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
Uf  IBGE    CNES    value   year
ES  320120  2547678 2747    2020
ES  320120  2485656 1817    2020
ES  320120  3125416 2965    2020
ES  320120  2547678 2916    2021
ES  320120  2485656 2071    2021
ES  320120  3125416 3156    2021
```

Tks!

Comment: Check the solutions of problem 1 and problem 2 in the dupe link

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=['Uf', 'IBGE', 'CNES'], var_name='year')`